# Handling cache right?

Tags: ios, caching, memory

I’m developing an application.

I have came to the point where I can’t decide what’s a good caching strategy:

The app shows restaurants nearby with images and videos:

If you go to a restaurant it pops up. If you go away, it disappears. If you go there again, it appears again.

---

Therefore I cache the photos with [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) and the videos with a custom made video cacher.

So in a normal case when the user is walking in the city, the app downloads lots of images and videos, which may or may not be seen again.

I don’t know how other applications are working, but I made a function that deletes all image-video cache (that are not visible anymore) every 5 minutes.

---

Is that a good straregy? Or would it be better not to delete manually old photos-videos cache, IOS does it by itself?